# Another, but specific play/pause issue

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to implement play/pause and stop buttons in a toolbar for a simple stopwatch app. See code at http://swiftstub.com/722226472  I'm experiencing strange behavior: at first the play button does nothing. If I click on the stop button, the icon disappears and then the play/pause toggles and works correctly. Suggestions?  I'm using the latest swift and Xcode

Comment: You can compare your code with the other ones which published on blogs such as Ray's one rather than asking here.

Comment: Please don't link outside to code -- those sites tend to go away -- put the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

target should be self (not nil) in both of these lines:

```
var playButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: nil, action: Selector("playButtonPressed"))

var pauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:
    UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: nil, action: Selector("pauseButtonPressed"))
```

EDIT (based on comment): and you should move these lines to an init() because you can't initialize using self in a var initialized this way.

```
var playButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var pauseButton: UIBarButtonItem!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   playButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: Selector("playButtonPressed"))
   pauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: Selector("pauseButtonPressed"))
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let toolBarItems = [playButton]
    toolbar.setItems(toolBarItems, animated: false)
}
```

Since you never added these in to begin with, I suspect you just have another button in your Storyboard that isn't hooked up to anything.  Then you replace them on the first call to stop.

Comment: I only have two Bar Button Items: Play and Stop. If I replace nil to self in the target I get: (!) `Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject->()->ViewController' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`

Comment: I added more info -- move the var initialization to an init() so that you can access self.

Comment: Thanks, Lou. I tried to move them into an init(), but couldn't figure out how to do that correctly. - Sorry, I'm only on day 3 of learning Swift.

Comment: Update your question with your code (not on the other side of the link), just paste it into the question.

Comment: I put in some sample code -- I didn't check it -- if it gives an error, read it carefully and try to fix.  If you can't -- make a different question with the specific code, error text, and what you tried.

Comment: Got it all working. Thanks.

Comment: @EricC it would be nice to mark this answer as accepted.  Thanks.